# IE empty image = red cross :-/

Tags: asp.net, html

when my image is empty IE draws it like a red cross. Is there any way to avoid drawing red cross ?

or as I've got asp Image I can make it invisible, but then I need to check if this image contains something or not.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Handler.ashx"/>
```

I need to load into byte[] x = { ??? }; an white pixel in image/jpeg format

my solution make me crazy ! 
here is it :

```
   <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Auth;

using System.Configuration;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    { get{ return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
           byte[] imageContent = Auth.User.GetImageFromDataBase();
           if (imageContent != null)
               context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageContent, 0, imageContent.Length);
           else
           {
               byte[] x = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x4a, 0x46, 0x49, 0x46, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x64, 
0x0, 0x64, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xec, 0x0, 0x11, 0x44, 0x75, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x79, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 
0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1b, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xee, 0x0, 0xe, 0x41, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 
0x0, 0x64, 0xc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0xff, 0xdb, 0x0, 0x84, 0x0, 0x11, 0xc, 0xc, 0xc, 
0xd, 0xc, 0x11, 0xd, 0xd, 0x11, 0x19, 0x10, 0xe, 0x10, 0x19, 0x1d, 0x16, 0x11, 0x11, 0x16, 
0x1d, 0x22, 0x17, 0x17, 0x17, 0x17, 0x17, 0x22, 0x21, 0x1a, 0x1d, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1a, 0x21, 
0x21, 0x26, 0x28, 0x2b, 0x28, 0x26, 0x21, 0x34, 0x34, 0x38, 0x38, 0x34, 0x34, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 
0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x10, 
0x13, 0x15, 0x13, 0x17, 0x14, 0x14, 0x17, 0x16, 0x12, 0x15, 0x12, 0x16, 0x1c, 0x16, 0x18, 0x18, 
0x16, 0x1c, 0x29, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x1e, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x29, 0x35, 0x26, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x21, 0x26, 
0x35, 0x2f, 0x32, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x32, 0x2f, 0x39, 0x39, 0x35, 0x35, 0x39, 0x39, 0x41, 0x41, 
0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x0, 
0x11, 0x8, 0x0, 0x64, 0x0, 0x64, 0x3, 0x1, 0x22, 0x0, 0x2, 0x11, 0x1, 0x3, 0x11, 0x1, 
0xff, 0xc4, 0x0, 0x75, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x3, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x5, 0x6, 0x4, 0x2, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 
0x1, 0x4, 0x1, 0x3, 0x1, 0x3, 0x6, 0xc, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x11, 0x12, 0x5, 0x6, 0x21, 0x31, 0x71, 0x13, 0x41, 0x51, 0xa1, 0x22, 
0xb3, 0x35, 0x61, 0x32, 0x52, 0x62, 0x33, 0x73, 0x14, 0x34, 0x74, 0x15, 0x36, 0x7, 0x91, 0x42, 
0x92, 0xb2, 0xd2, 0x93, 0x54, 0x11, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xda, 0x0, 0xc, 0x3, 0x1, 0x0, 0x2, 0x11, 
0x3, 0x11, 0x0, 0x3f, 0x0, 0xde, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x45, 0x25, 0xaa, 0xd1, 0x48, 0xc8, 0xa5, 0x99, 0x91, 
0xc9, 0x27, 0x48, 0xd8, 0xe7, 0x23, 0x5c, 0xe5, 0x55, 0xc7, 0xaa, 0x8a, 0xb9, 0x5e, 0xa0, 0x4a, 
0x8, 0xe7, 0xb1, 0x5e, 0xbb, 0x11, 0xf6, 0x25, 0x64, 0x2c, 0x55, 0xc2, 0x3a, 0x47, 0x23, 0x13, 
0x3d, 0xb8, 0xcb, 0x88, 0x3f, 0x36, 0xda, 0xff, 0x0, 0xed, 0x83, 0xfd, 0xac, 0xff, 0x0, 0x20, 
0x3a, 0xc1, 0x1c, 0x33, 0xc1, 0x3b, 0x75, 0xc1, 0x23, 0x25, 0x6f, 0xca, 0x63, 0x91, 0xc9, 0xfc, 
0x50, 0x90, 0x0, 0x39, 0xed, 0x6e, 0x14, 0x29, 0x26, 0x6d, 0xd9, 0x8a, 0xbe, 0x7b, 0x3c, 0x47, 
0xb5, 0x8a, 0xbd, 0xc8, 0xaa, 0x78, 0xab, 0xbb, 0x6d, 0x97, 0x5d, 0xa2, 0xa5, 0xb8, 0x67, 0x7f, 
0xc8, 0x63, 0xda, 0xe7, 0x7f, 0x4e, 0x72, 0x7, 0x58, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x8b, 
0xe5, 0xbf, 0xaa, 0x76, 0xf, 0xad, 0x8f, 0xdb, 0x30, 0xda, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x5b, 0xfa, 0xa7, 0x60, 
0xfa, 0xd8, 0xfd, 0xb3, 0x0, 0x9f, 0xf7, 0x1f, 0xdc, 0x70, 0x7e, 0x29, 0x9e, 0xce, 0x52, 0x6a, 
0xbc, 0x23, 0x8e, 0xc9, 0x5a, 0x19, 0x1f, 0x5d, 0xea, 0xe7, 0xb1, 0xae, 0x72, 0xf8, 0x8f, 0xed, 
0x54, 0x45, 0x5f, 0x29, 0xf, 0xee, 0x3f, 0xb8, 0xe0, 0xfc, 0x53, 0x3d, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x75, 0xb7, 
0xee, 0x58, 0xda, 0xf1, 0x35, 0x9b, 0x26, 0xb6, 0x35, 0x8d, 0x46, 0xbb, 0x52, 0xf5, 0x44, 0x4e, 
0x8a, 0x5, 0x7f, 0x20, 0xda, 0x99, 0xc4, 0xec, 0xd3, 0xdd, 0xb6, 0x89, 0x1f, 0x1b, 0x1d, 0x26, 
0x89, 0x61, 0x73, 0x95, 0x51, 0xdf, 0xcd, 0xa7, 0x3e, 0x56, 0xaa, 0x22, 0xe7, 0x26, 0x93, 0x94, 
0xef, 0xcb, 0xb4, 0x6d, 0x1f, 0x68, 0x83, 0xef, 0x36, 0x15, 0x19, 0x5f, 0x3d, 0x74, 0xab, 0x93, 
0x2a, 0xf5, 0x4f, 0x9a, 0x9e, 0x9c, 0x14, 0xaf, 0xda, 0x79, 0x1f, 0x25, 0xbd, 0x5e, 0x4d, 0xea, 
0x16, 0x52, 0xdb, 0xab, 0xbb, 0x57, 0x82, 0xd5, 0x4d, 0x4f, 0xf3, 0xa6, 0x35, 0x39, 0x72, 0xb8, 
0xc6, 0x57, 0x18, 0xf2, 0x21, 0xeb, 0x9d, 0xfb, 0xcf, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x9f, 0x41, 0xe2, 0xbb, 0x3e, 
0x6f, 0x8f, 0x16, 0xaf, 0x40, 0x13, 0xed, 0x1c, 0x2a, 0xac, 0x91, 0x36, 0xee, 0xfb, 0xae, 0xe5, 
0xf9, 0xf0, 0xf9, 0x1a, 0xf7, 0xb9, 0x1a, 0xc5, 0x5e, 0xb8, 0x5d, 0x2a, 0x8a, 0xe5, 0xf3, 0xf5, 
0xc1, 0xef, 0x77, 0xe0, 0xdb, 0x64, 0xb5, 0xdf, 0x2e, 0xd4, 0xc7, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x1a, 0x6a, 0x8b, 
0x43, 0xdc, 0xad, 0x73, 0x9b, 0xd5, 0x11, 0x75, 0x2a, 0xe3, 0x3e, 0x74, 0x35, 0x66, 0x5a, 0xc7, 
0x2b, 0xde, 0x61, 0xb1, 0x2c, 0x4c, 0xe3, 0xd6, 0x65, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x5b, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x98, 
0x7a, 0x35, 0x70, 0x8e, 0x4c, 0x40, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0x58, 0x71, 0x6b, 0x9b, 0x95, 0xbd, 0xa6, 0x37, 
0x6e, 0x71, 0x49, 0x15, 0x98, 0xd5, 0x58, 0xae, 0x95, 0xaa, 0xc7, 0x48, 0xd4, 0x44, 0x56, 0xbf, 
0xb, 0xde, 0x5c, 0x94, 0x7c, 0x6b, 0x91, 0xae, 0xfc, 0xcb, 0x2e, 0x5a, 0xdf, 0x65, 0x5a, 0xce, 
0x6b, 0x55, 0xaa, 0xff, 0x0, 0x13, 0x3a, 0xb3, 0xf3, 0x19, 0x8c, 0x60, 0xbc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x3, 0x19, 0xf9, 0xfd, 0x9d, 0xa7, 0x96, 0xda, 0xad, 0xbb, 0xd8, 0x72, 0x6d, 0xf2, 0xb5, 
0x56, 0xbe, 0xaf, 0xa3, 0x66, 0xbd, 0x2e, 0x62, 0xf4, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x8a, 0xd3, 0x9e, 0xfd, 0xca, 
0xfc, 0x83, 0x97, 0xed, 0x6c, 0xdb, 0x55, 0x66, 0x8a, 0x92, 0xb6, 0x49, 0x66, 0x44, 0x54, 0x6f, 
0xa8, 0xff, 0x0, 0x11, 0xdd, 0xbe, 0x4e, 0x88, 0x99, 0xf3, 0xa9, 0xb2, 0xbb, 0xb7, 0x50, 0xbe, 
0xd4, 0x65, 0xda, 0xf1, 0xd8, 0x46, 0xfc, 0x5d, 0x6d, 0x45, 0x56, 0xf7, 0x2f, 0x6a, 0xa, 0x5b, 
0x6d, 0xa, 0xd, 0x56, 0xd2, 0xaf, 0x1d, 0x74, 0x77, 0xc6, 0xd0, 0xd4, 0x45, 0x77, 0x7a, 0xf6, 
0xa8, 0x19, 0xbf, 0xdc, 0x7f, 0x71, 0xc1, 0xf8, 0xa6, 0x7b, 0x39, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x1f, 0xb9, 0x57, 
0xfa, 0xa6, 0x7f, 0x6a, 0x1f, 0x6c, 0xd4, 0xab, 0x6d, 0x89, 0x1d, 0xb8, 0x23, 0xb1, 0x1a, 0x2e, 
0xa4, 0x64, 0xac, 0x6c, 0x8d, 0x47, 0x22, 0x63, 0x38, 0x72, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xa4, 0xad, 0x6b, 0x5a, 
0xd4, 0x6b, 0x51, 0x1a, 0xd6, 0xa6, 0x11, 0x13, 0xa2, 0x22, 0x20, 0x1f, 0x4a, 0x2e, 0x5b, 0xb1, 
0xbf, 0x79, 0xdb, 0x34, 0xc1, 0xf7, 0xba, 0xee, 0xf1, 0x20, 0x4e, 0xcd, 0x4b, 0x8c, 0x39, 0x99, 
0xf8, 0x53, 0xd3, 0x82, 0xf4, 0x1, 0x94, 0xda, 0x39, 0xad, 0x3f, 0xd, 0xb4, 0xf7, 0xad, 0x54, 
0xaf, 0xc2, 0x88, 0xc9, 0x56, 0x46, 0xae, 0x97, 0xb9, 0x3c, 0xbd, 0x13, 0xd5, 0x55, 0xf2, 0xe7, 
0xa7, 0xc2, 0x75, 0x5f, 0xe7, 0x1b, 0x5, 0x48, 0xd5, 0x62, 0x9d, 0x6d, 0x4b, 0x8f, 0x56, 0x38, 
0x91, 0x57, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x54, 0x46, 0xa1, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x6c, 0xdb, 0xaf, 0x63, 0xed, 0x95, 0xa2, 
0x9d, 0x53, 0xa2, 0x2b, 0xd8, 0x8e, 0x72, 0x77, 0x2f, 0x6a, 0x10, 0xd5, 0xd8, 0xb6, 0x6a, 0x8f, 
0xf1, 0x2b, 0xd2, 0x86, 0x39, 0x13, 0xb1, 0xe8, 0xc4, 0x57, 0x27, 0x72, 0xae, 0x55, 0x0, 0xa1, 
0xe0, 0x14, 0xae, 0x57, 0xad, 0x72, 0xcd, 0x98, 0x5d, 0xb, 0x2d, 0x48, 0xd7, 0x44, 0x8f, 0xe8, 
0xaa, 0x89, 0xab, 0x2b, 0x85, 0xeb, 0x8f, 0x58, 0xd7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7, 0xff, 0xd9};
               context.Response.OutputStream.Write(x, 0, x.Length);
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also search for "broken images" here, that will give you a number of alternative options.

Comment: @Lazarus what do you mean ? . . .

Comment: use the search field at the top of this page to search for "broken images" and you'll see a whole raft of questions and answer related to the same issue you have, i.e. img tags referring to images that no longer exist or have been moved.

Comment: now I've got my own awesome solution , but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to show a default image if the image is empty in your `handler.ashx` file. We do the same thing for phone book in our intranet.

Comment: ... that's possible , but I no need there default image. I think I will use it if I find no solutions how just hide the cross :) thank you.

Comment: @nCdy, to add to Shoban reply, you could make the default image a 1px by 1px transparent gif so it is not noticeable by end-users..